# how to Fix "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: null is not a known Entity type." error after 1 hour of running

Tags: java, jpa, ejb, oracle-adf

After 70 minutes of page running the main iterator in my view Binding is refreshing and throwing the below Exception
'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: null is not a known Entity type.'

i have already tried changing the iterator's refresh property to never and it still refreshing.

here is my Entity

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({ @NamedQuery(name = "Employees.findById", query = "select o from Employees o where o.employeeId = :employeeId")})
public class Employees implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID", nullable = false)
    private Integer employeeId;
    private Integer salary;
    public Employees() {
    }

    public Integer getEmployeeId() {
        return employeeId;
    }

    public void setEmployeeId(Integer employeeId) {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
    }

    public Integer getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(Integer salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

}
```

and here is my session bean

```
@Stateless(name = "HrFacade", mappedName = "Hr_EJB_JPA-Model-HrFacade")
public class HrFacadeBean implements HrFacade, HrFacadeLocal {
    @Resource
    SessionContext sessionContext;
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "Model")
    private EntityManager em;

    public HrFacadeBean() {
    }

    public Employees mergeEmployees(Employees employees) {
        return em.merge(employees);
    }

    public Employees getEmployeeByDepEmpId(Integer employeeId){
        if(employeeId != null){
            return em.createNamedQuery("Employees.findById",Employees.class)
                 .setParameter("employeeId", employeeId)
                 .getResultList().get(0);
        }
        return new Employees();
    }
```

and here is my Binding

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<pageDefinition xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adfm/uimodel" version="12.2.1.16.48" id="view1PageDef"
                Package="oracle.view.pageDefs">
  <parameters/>
  <executables>
    <variableIterator id="variables"/>
    <iterator Binds="root" RangeSize="25" DataControl="HrFacadeBean" id="HrFacadeBeanIterator"/>
    <accessorIterator MasterBinding="HrFacadeBeanIterator" Binds="employeeByDepEmpId" RangeSize="25"
                      DataControl="HrFacadeBean" BeanClass="oracle.model.Employees" id="employeeByDepEmpIdIterator"/>
  </executables>
  <bindings>
    <attributeValues IterBinding="employeeByDepEmpIdIterator" id="employeeId">
      <AttrNames>
        <Item Value="employeeId"/>
      </AttrNames>
    </attributeValues>
    <attributeValues IterBinding="employeeByDepEmpIdIterator" id="salary">
      <AttrNames>
        <Item Value="salary"/>
      </AttrNames>
    </attributeValues>
    <methodAction id="employeesMerge" RequiresUpdateModel="true" Action="invokeMethod" MethodName="mergeEmployees"
                  IsViewObjectMethod="false" DataControl="HrFacadeBean"
                  InstanceName="data.HrFacadeBean.dataProvider"
                  ReturnName="data.HrFacadeBean.methodResults.employeesMerge_mergeEmployees_dataControl_dataProvider_mergeEmployees_result">
      <NamedData NDName="employees" NDValue="#{bindings.employeeByDepEmpIdIterator.currentRow.dataProvider}"
                 NDType="oracle.model.Employees"/>
    </methodAction>
  </bindings>
</pageDefinition>
```

and here is my page binding

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<pageDefinition xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adfm/uimodel" version="12.2.1.16.48" id="untitled2PageDef"
                Package="oracle.view.pageDefs">
  <parameters/>
  <executables>
    <variableIterator id="variables"/>
    <taskFlow id="taskflow11" taskFlowId="/WEB-INF/task-flow-1.xml#task-flow-1" activation="conditional"
              xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/controller/binding"
              RefreshCondition="#{pageFlowScope.employeeId ne null}" active="#{pageFlowScope.employeeId eq null}">
      <parameters>
        <parameter id="employeeId" value="1212"/>
      </parameters>
    </taskFlow>
  </executables>
  <bindings/>
</pageDefinition>
```

i can merge my work normally up until 1 hour and 10 minutes exactly the iterator tries to refresh to go through getEmployeeByDepEmpId and it will throw the exception, so does anyone have an idea why the iterator have this behavior and how to change it ? thank you in advance.

Comment: It's very good that you provided your code and configuration. It would be even better if you remove *as much as possible* from it to produce a Minimal Reproducible Example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Start removing columns, methods etc. until you get the minimal skeleton which still reproduces your error. Maybe by doing this you will find the root cause **yourself**, or at least you will make it pleasanter for us to help you.

Comment: removed as much as i can, i only kept the entity id and one field to change and i removed one parameter also

Comment: That's much better :)

Comment: Hey William, In your ViewController project web.xml file what is "Session Timeout" attribute value ?

Comment: it's not specified but i think the session timeout affects the inactivity of the page. my issue is even if the user is active on the page the iterator will refresh

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of your sentence "go through `getEmployeeByDepEmpId` and it will throw the exception". In this method you handle the situation when `employeeId` is `null` - this method cannot throw the exception. Where is the exception *really* thrown?

Comment: What exactly do you intend to reach by the setting `RefreshCondition="#{pageFlowScope.employeeId ne null}" active="#{pageFlowScope.employeeId eq null}"`? See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23549_01/web.1111/b31974/taskflows_regions.htm#CHDEIFBB and https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23549_01/web.1111/b31974/taskflows_regions.htm#CHDFCHIF

Comment: i was trying to tell the iterator to refresh only if "#{pageFlowScope.employeeId eq null}"

Comment: also i tried without setting the refresh condition and the active properties and the issue will remain

Comment: Where *exactly* is the exception thrown? It cannot be in `getEmployeeByDepEmpId()` as you wrote. It must be somewhere else. What about the fields of the entity? If `employeeId` is `null`, you return just a **completely empty** object, with all its fields equals `null`. Could this be the source of the exception?

Comment: it is indeed the source of the exception, but only because the second time the iterator refreshes and enters getEmployeeByDepEmpId() employeeId is null. And when i tried to get it from pageFlowScope instead of the function's parameter, it is replacing my version of employee with the database version.

Comment: No, you so handle the situation in `getEmployeeByDepEmpId()` when `employeeId` is `null`, you return an empty object, not `null`. Try to change the class `Employees` (which, btw should be named `Employee`!!!) so its **fields** are never `null`.

Comment: Hey William it's about your session timeout on your web.xml. The default value is 60 minutes so your iterator are reset. You need to play with this value and the value that warn your user about an iminitent timeout. It will fix this issue 100%.

Comment: @Cedric i will try it now (if i put the value -1 what will happen ?)

Comment: i tried it and it didn't work @Cedric

Comment: Don't put -1. :) It need to have a timeout at some point to free memory and retreive ressources. You need to check with your user how much inactivity time they can accept without needing to reconnect. Set this value as timeout and set the warning time 2 minutes before. You'll find tutorials on this easily.